# not able to add annotation to mapView iOS from a different method

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm trying to add a annotation to the map from a different button method, however it doesn't show up. It doesn't give an error either.

Where as all the annotations which I have mentioned in the mapView method, they are being displayed.

```
-(void) testButton {


    /// custom location coordinate
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userLocationNew2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-80.050003, -13.416667);

    // use that cusom coordinate
    MKCoordinateRegion region2 = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocationNew2, 20000, 20000);
    [mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region2] animated:YES];

    // Add an annotation

    MKPointAnnotation *point2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point2.coordinate = userLocationNew2;
    point2.title = @"Check";
    // point2.subtitle = @"Right here oooooo!!!";

    [mapView addAnnotation:point2];
}
```

The other method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

 /// custom location coordinate
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userLocationNew2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-73.050003, -13.416667);

    // use that cusom coordinate
    MKCoordinateRegion region2 = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocationNew2, 20000, 20000);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region2] animated:YES];

    // Add an annotation

    MKPointAnnotation *point2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point2.coordinate = userLocationNew2;
    point2.title = @"Basic";

}
```

Comment: You aren't using self.mapView in your first method, so you may be referring to a different variable. The default name for the automatic iVar would be _mapview

Comment: Maybe you need to call [map setNeedsDisplay]; to refresh it.

Comment: You know those coordinates are in Antarctica, right?  Also, in didUpdateUserLocation, you are not calling addAnnotation.

Comment: @Anna: heh, yeah..it's Antarctica on purpose. Working on a small project based on Florida, just adding a pin for myself in Antarctica :p